# How to prevent responding to arp scan requests from outside (except the router) in ubuntu?

Tags: security, iptables, arp, spoofing

How do I prevent my computer from responding to arp scans in my network? A solution using iptables or something similar is very welcome.

The network interface is wlan0.

Some malicious users are using arp attacks (spoofing) to modify the arp table in the router and thus, prevent me from accessing the internet.
If I can stop my computer from responding to those, I should be safe because the malicious user wouldn't know that I'm connected to the network.

Comment: I'm not so sure that stopping your computer from responding to ARP (and then how will the router know your MAC address anyway?) would stop somebody trying to boot you off the network by impersonating you. I guess you'd want switches and bridges that sniff DHCP and filter spoofed IP and ARP for that...

Comment: @Celada Do you think it would work if I stop responding to all ARP except those coming from the router IP?

Comment: @Celada The people doing this have a software (in windows called netcut) which first tries to look for all the computers connected to the network and then does the spoofing. It doesn't store the list of computers for future use. There are more than 200 people in the campus. So, they are not targeting me particularly :)

Comment: Might want to report this to your system administrator, if you haven't already.

Comment: You can filter ARP requests with `ebtables`. But as Celada noted that's probably not going to solve your problem.